# Open a browser link not working on Mac OS

Tags: java

On click of a button, I want the application to open a URL.
So I am doing this:

```
Desktop desktop = Desktop.isDesktopSupported() ? Desktop.getDesktop() : null;
    System.out.println("Hey "+desktop);
    if (desktop != null && desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
        try {
            desktop.browse(new URL("http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572").toURI());
            System.out.println("here");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But `Desktop.isDesktopSupported()` returns false. I am on Mac OS X 10.7.5. Any alternative?

Comment: Works just fine for me. OSX 10.7.5, build 11G63b.

Comment: Hmmm doesn't on my comp. Its unreliable, will have to look at alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac, this does the job. Thanks to [this](http://alvinalexander.com/java/mac-java-open-url-browser-osascript):

```
private void openUrlInBrowser(String url)
{
 Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
 String[] args = { "osascript", "-e", "open location \"" + url + "\"" };
 try
 {
  Process process = runtime.exec(args);
 }
 catch (IOException e)
 {
// do what you want with this
 }
}
```